# Codename one SQLite data issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop, codenameone

I am working on Codename one SQLite project, While I am getting some issues, I am trying that when I am clicking on some specific date on the calendar then it will check whether that date present in the database or not, but when I am firstly click on a particular date after the application starts it gives accurate occurrence of that date, but at the second time it add previous date occurrence to the present date occurrence and display the summation of that. So how can I resolve it?

**Below is my code:-**

```
public class Customised extends Calendar{
         ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();



         public Customised(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
             dayButton.setText(""+day);
       dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

               try{
        cur =  db.executeQuery("SELECT Date from CalendarData WHERE Date = ? ", dateLabel.getText());
         int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
                      if(columns > 0) {
                    boolean next = cur.next();
                    if(next) {

                        String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                            columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                        }
                        while(next) {
                            Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                            String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                                currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                            }
                            data.add(currentRowArray);
                            next = cur.next();
                        }
                        Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                        data.toArray(arr);
                    }
                      }
             }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
               int i;
               for( i = 0 ; i< data.size(); i++){
                   Log.p(data.get(i)[0]);
               }
               Label a = new Label(dateLabel.getText());
               Label b = new Label(""+i);
               Container container1 = TableLayout.encloseIn(2, a,b);
               calendar.add(container1);
              Util.cleanup(data);

              // dayButton.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xef5555);
     //  dayButton.setText("* "+day);

           }      
       });
    }

    @Override
    protected Button createDay() {
       Button day = new Button();
        day.setAlignment(CENTER);
        day.setUIID("CalendarDay");
        day.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        day.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return day;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: which method is called upon date click?

Comment: dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
}}

Answer (score 1):

**I got an answer to this problem:-**

```
@Override
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {

         dayButton.setText(""+day);
   dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

           try{
    cur =  db.executeQuery("SELECT Date from CalendarData WHERE Date = ? ", dateLabel.getText());
     int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
                  if(columns > 0) {
                boolean next = cur.next();
                if(next) {

                    String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                    }
                    while(next) {
                        Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                        String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                            currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                        }
                        data.add(currentRowArray);
                        next = cur.next();
                    }
                    Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                    data.toArray(arr);
                }
                  }
         }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

           for( i = 0 ; i< data.size(); i++){
               Log.p(data.get(i)[0]);
           }
           Label a = new Label(dateLabel.getText());
           Label b = new Label(""+i);

           Container container1 = TableLayout.encloseIn(2, a,b);
           if(calendar.contains(container1)== true){
               calendar.removeComponent(container1);
           calendar.add(container1);
           }else{
               calendar.add(container1);
           }

          data.clear();

          // dayButton.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xef5555);
 //  dayButton.setText("* "+day);

       }      
   });
}
```

**And thanks for response.**